# How to put the return data in a php variable when using ajax post

Tags: php, ajax, post

I'm currently using an ajax post to retrieve data from another page. For reusing the returned value in future, I want to assign it to a php variable. Is it possible?

```
success: function(data) {
 $('#display').html(data);
}
```

Comment: Are you really talking about php variable or js variable?

Comment: php variable. in the success function, the data is already there but I want to put it on a php variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The php file completes its execution in the server first and the result is passed to the browser. The javascript (ie, ajax) part is then executed in your browser. Read the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30801209/assign-ajax-response-values-to-php-variables) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var jvalue = 'this is javascript value';

<?php $abc = "<script>document.write(jvalue)</script>"?>   
</script>
```